# How to call get method on an Array Object - Java

Tags: java, list, object, get, hashmap

I have 2 classes, in SumUserCart i initialize the array of object, then i have to call get method on productID in ProductCart, any solutions?

The data is in list

```
List<SumUserCart> cartList
```

SumUserCart class:

```
public class SumUserCart {
    int userId;
    ProductsCart[] products;

    public SumUserCart(int userId, ProductsCart[] products) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SumUserCart{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", products=" + Arrays.toString(products) +
                '}';
    }

    public ProductsCart[] getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
 
   //getters & setters here
}
```

ProductCart class:

```
public class ProductsCart {
    int productId;
    int quantity;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductsCart{" +
                "productId=" + productId +
                ", quantity=" + quantity +
                '}';
    }

    public ProductsCart() {}

    public ProductsCart(int productId, int quantity) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    //getters & setters here
}
```

That's my function, where i am trying to print the product id's:

```
private static void printTheCart(List<SumUserCart> cartList){
        for (SumUserCart cartsByUser : cartList) {
            System.out.println("User Id: " + cartsByUser.getUserId() + " = " + Arrays.toString(cartsByUser.getProducts()));
            //System.out.println(cartsByUser.getProducts());
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think I don't unterstand the exact question. Do you want to know how to call a getter on the int-attribute productId or the ProductsCard array?

Answer (score 1):

The same way as it is done with arrays! Accessing using index values.
Since you want to access from ArrayList use below code:

```java
//get 0th element of cartList, which will be a SumUserCart object
SumUserCart suc = cartList.get(0);
//creating productsCarts object array:
ProductsCarts[] pc = suc.getProducts();
//Now use getProductId() method:
int pid = pc[0].getProductId(0);
```

Comment: I am asking how to call this from List<SumUserCart> cartList, example: cartListc.getProducts().getProductId, but i cant do this, because its an array

Comment: OK, use cartList.get(indexOfTheSumUserCart).prodArray[0].getProductId(); I will update my answer.

Comment: Arrays.toString(c.getProducts()) Prints an array containing productId and quantity, i want to get just productId

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Use ".getProductId()" too after mentioning the index of "products" of SumUserCart of cartList.

Comment: i cant use products[0], only getters, still not working

Comment: Sorry! Use ".getProducts" of SumUserCart instead of products[0]. Don't complicate stuff, create a SumUserCart and ProductsCart object.

Comment: you mean this? cartsByUser.getProducts().getProductId();

Comment: Nope! Creating a SumUserCart objects assigning value, creating ProductsCarts objects and using ".getProductsId" on it. Refer to my current post edit answer!

Comment: Cant we call this without creating two Objects? How it its, i could call in example u.getAddress().getGeolocation().getLongitude() but i cant do my task the same way because in the middle is an array?

Comment: I mean SumUserCart automatically creates this object, when i get my data there, but we can't get reference to it as in other example because its a array?

Comment: int pid = pc[0].getProductId();  instead of getProductId(0) and its ok

Comment: I dont think it works but, if works for you then very well! you can avoid creating SumUserCarts object but, ProductsCarts objects is needed.

Answer (score 0):

That's the right method to call this

```
private static void printTheCart(List<SumUserCart> cartList){
        for (SumUserCart cartsByUser : cartList) {
            System.out.println("User Id: " + cartsByUser.getUserId() + " = " + Arrays.toString(cartsByUser.getProducts()));
            ProductsCart[] pcx = cartsByUser.getProducts();
            for (ProductsCart pc : pcx)
                System.out.println(pc.getProductId());
                
        }
```

Comment: Explain how this solves the problem faced by OP.

Comment: It retrieves the product ID of each cart and products that appear in that cart.